# call number project visual basic

Tags: vb.net, select, case

1) Create a Windows Form Application “CallNumber”.
2) Design and define the GUI, name each control appropriately by including the
control type in the name. For example --- CallNumberTextBox. Modify the other
properties if needed.
3) Create and define GetLocation button_click event handler method by double
clicking the Get Location button in the design view. Perform the following tasks
in this event handler method:
  a. Declare variable for call number which should be an Integer number.
  b. Get input data (call number of a book) from the TextBox and save it in the
call number variable declared in the previous step. Suppose user will
always input numeric integer number.
  c. Define selection statements to determine and display the location of the book.

This is the code I have so far. I don't get an output. Can you help me?

```
    Dim call_num As Integer = Val(CallNumberTextBox.Text) 'get call number
    Dim CallNumberResultLabel As String

    Select Case call_num
        Case 100 To 199 And " 901 to 1000"
            CallNumberResultLabel = "Building A"
        Case 200 To 349
            CallNumberResultLabel = "Building B"
        Case 401 To 599
            CallNumberResultLabel = "Building B"
        Case 600 To 899
            CallNumberResultLabel = "Building C"
        Case Is < 1000
            CallNumberResultLabel = "Building C"
        Case 350 To 400
            CallNumberResultLabel = "Building D"
        Case Else
            CallNumberResultLabel = "Error"

    End Select

    CallNumberTextBox.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: When you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: You are missing a lot of  Sub declarations and block starts to make any sense of that.  but you should turn on option strict

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: The user has to enter a number and the result should be displayed according to the number. For Example is the user entered Case 351 the output should be Building C. I don't get an output and I cannot figure out the issue

Comment: Your issue is that you never make it output anything! Nowhere in your code have you written that it should output anything, and you haven't told us either - So, _**where**_ is this output going to be displayed?

Comment: How do I write the output code? The output should be displayed where it says CallNumberResultLabel. The number should be taken from the CallNumberTextBox and the result should be shown in the label

Comment: So do `yourLabelName.Text = CallNumberResultLabel`.

Comment: That is not working for me either but thank you.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/as8INi

Comment: "Not working" isn't a description of your problem. I assure you it will work if you do it right. By the way, `yourLabelName` was meant to be replaced by the actual name of the label you added.

Comment: If you could tell me what happens or what error you get that would be helpful (also where you placed the code I wrote).

Comment: I tried with the code you gave, I inserted the code at the end before end select. By errror I mean the call number result label is blank and no building letter is shown in that area.

Comment: You mean you have both a string named `CallNumberResultLabel` and a label named `CallNumberResultLabel?` Remove the string declaration and then just use `CallNumberResultLabel.Text`.

Comment: Now I end up with building c as the result for any number I enter

Comment: Change back to `Dim call_num As Integer = Val(CallNumberTextBox.Text)`

Comment: thanks so much that works..... Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Change `Case 100 To 199 And " 901 to 1000"`  to `Case 100 To 199, 901 To 1000`

Comment: Also check out `Try/Catch`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by output,  You don't seem to be doing anything with `CallNumberResultLabel `.  I ran the code and entered 351 in the text box and put a breakpoint at `CallNumberTextBox.Focus()` and it worked.

Comment: I am supposed to get a building and an alphabet letter when I run the code but it is just blank.